# How does one plot a 3 dimensional table of numbers?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, tensors, charts

I've just spent three hours searching the documentation and this website for an answer.

I have a rank 3 tensor:

```
t = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}
```

How does one make a three-dimensional table of these numbers? Is there something like TensorForm3D?

Comment: You can plot data of the form `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}...}` with `ListPlot`, and you can plot data of the form `{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}...}` with `ListPointPlot3D`. There are also functions for plotting 4D data of the form `{{x1, y1, z1, f1}, {x2, y2, z2, f2}...}` using `ListSliceDensityPlot3D` and related functions. Your data doesn't seem to be in any of those formats. What exactly are you trying to plot?

Comment: The simplest way to display it is to use MatrixForm -- it gives nested 2-D matrices.

Comment: @MassDefect I can put my data in the form {{x1, y1, z1, f1}, {x2, y2, z2, f2}...} where f1 is a number and f2 is a different number, etc. I then want a 3D array of numbers graphic where f1 appears at position {x1,y1,z1}, etc.

Comment: @Michael you can use something like: `data={{x,y,z,f},....}; coord=data[[All,1;;3]];lbl=data[[All,4]]; Graphics3D[Table[Text[lbl[[i]],coord[[i]]].{i,1,Length@data}]]`
It will draw the 3D image where fourth element of data entries will be drawn at coordinates (x,y,z)

Comment: @bill s What is the correspondence between the MatrixForm elements and the row, column, page numbering?

Comment: @bill s For example, are the data in the correct form of {row, column, page} if I do: prob = {{{111, 112, 113, 114, 115}, {121, 122, 123, 124, 125}}, {{211,
      212, 213, 214, 215}, {221, 222, 223, 224, 225}}, {{311, 312, 
     313, 314, 315}, {321, 322, 323, 324, 325}}, {{411, 412, 413, 414,
      415}, {421, 422, 423, 424, 425}}};
MatrixForm[prob]

Comment: Michael -- you can put the data in any order you want using Transpose (to change the order of the dimensions). For example: MatrixForm[Transpose[prob, {1, 3, 2}]] or MatrixForm[Transpose[prob, {3, 2, 1}]]. It works in any number of dimensions.

Comment: So what is the default order?

Comment: The default order: m[[1,2,3]] means page 1, row 2, column 3.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the comments, the OP stated: I can put my data in the form {{x1, y1, z1, f1}, {x2, y2, z2, f2}...} where f1 is a number and f2 is a different number, etc. I then want a 3D array of numbers graphic where f1 appears at position {x1,y1,z1}.

Here is some random data in the given form. It is then broken into the locations (first three parameters) and the values (fourth parameter). We can then plot all the numbers at their respective locations using GraphPlot3D:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 4}];
locs = data[[All, 1 ;; 3]];
vals = data[[All, 4]];
GraphPlot3D[Thread[vals -> vals], VertexLabeling -> True,
            VertexCoordinateRules -> locs]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the input data is of the form `{{x1, y1, z1, f1}, {x2, y2, z2, f2}, ...}`, you can use [`BubbleChart3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart3D.html)

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[1, {10, 4}]
```

> {{0.817389, 0.11142, 0.789526, 0.187803}, {0.241361, 0.0657388, 0.542247,  0.231155},
>   {0.396006, 0.700474, 0.211826, 0.748657}, {0.422851, 0.247495, 0.977172, 0.825163},
>   {0.925275, 0.578056, 0.29287, 0.208051}, {0.580474, 0.128821, 0.306427, 0.712012}, 
>    {0.390582, 0.819967, 0.325351, 0.59326}, {0.518774, 0.169013, 0.472565, 0.807161},
>   {0.0118355, 0.316876, 0.789804, 0.011978}, {0.391276, 0.458902, 0.458845, 0.727517}}

```
BubbleChart3D[SortBy[data, Last],  ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",  
 ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[{Sort@data[[All, -1]]}, LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"]
```

[image]

If you want to replace bubbles with text you can use a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
cEF = Text[Framed[Style[#2[[-1]], Bold, Opacity[1]], Background -> White, 
  FrameStyle -> Gray], Mean[Transpose@#]] &;

BubbleChart3D[data, ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", ChartElementFunction -> cEF]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 3}];

ListPointPlot3D[data,
 BoxRatios -> 1,
 BaseStyle -> Thickness[0.01],
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 Filling -> Bottom,
 LabelingFunction -> (Callout[Round[#]]&)]
```

[image]